# Whats the alternative for file_get_contents in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

`file_get_contents($url)` is **working** but Laravel functions not working.

File is available at this URL

```
$url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airports.dat";
```

this simple PHP function is working and retrieving the file

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
```

but all these Laravel functions which mentioned below are showing this error :

> "File does not exist at path
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airports.dat"

Code is available below:

```
use File; // i have included this before class
use Storage; // i have included this before class

    $url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpatokal/openflights/master/data/airports.dat";
    $content = File::get($url); // not working

    $content = Storage::get($url); // not working

    $content = File::get(url($url)); // not working

    $content = file_get_contents($url); // working fine

    return $content;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest guzzlehttp ([Github Page](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle))

Easy Usage:

Installation:

```
 composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

Send request and get response:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->get($url);
$content = (string) $res->getBody();
```

Comment: Way too easy to implement. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate , we can use file facade. To get information from external sites, we can use guzzle.
Link is https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle